# Video inside a tab

Tags: codenameone

If in a Tabs I add a tab containing a video, I have a weird effect exspecially on Android (like a flickering). Since MediaPlayer is a native player, I suspect that Tabs and native components work bad together. Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Where do you get this flickering? When the video is playing on the currently visible tab or is this when transitioning tabs?
Is this happening only when the video is playing or does it have that impact when paused?

Comment: Solved. I was wrong: the cause of this issue was an incorrect useless use of revalidate, that was invoked many times in a short time. I replaced the revalidate with a repaint and... that’s all :)